# Loading a view from XIB and displaying in Storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, storyboard, xib

For the long period of time I've been working with custom views with `xib` files.

In this case, I needed to do following things:

1. Create a `xib`-file and `swift`-file, both with the same name.
2. Select the view, set its custom class to the class in `swift`-file.
3. Continue working, and, when needed, I create the view like so:

   ```
   public extension UIView {
   class func fromXib() -> UIView {
       return NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed(self.nameOfClass, owner: nil, options: nil).first as! UIView
   }
   ```

Ok, it is working, no problem. But in different project I started working more with Storyboard. I wanted custom views to be displayed there despite  they were designed in `xib`-file (I do so, for example, when the view appears on a several screens).

So, to solve this task I did next steps:

1. Create a `xib`-file and `swift`-file, both with the same name.
2. Instead of setting the custom class, I set the `File's owner` to the `swift`-file's class. (So the class of my view is not set, `UIView` by default).
3. I add the following code to the view's lifecycle methods:

   ```
   required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
       super.init(coder: aDecoder)
       setup()
   }

   override init(frame: CGRect) {
       super.init(frame: frame)
       setup()
   }

   func setup() {
       let v = NSBundle(forClass: self.dynamicType).loadNibNamed(self.nameOfClass, owner: self, options: nil).first as? UIView
       addSubview(v!)
       v?.frame = self.bounds
   }
   ```
4. I mark the view as `@IBDesignable`.

Again, everything is ok, I add a view to the storyboard's screen, set its class to my custom class, and ta-daa, it renders in Interface Builder, and loaded in runtime of my app.

**The problem is**: How do I wire there things together? If I use my `fromXib` method, the app crashes: `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<NSObject 0x7f9ea2d5b240> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key hoursLabel.`

It would be really convenient if I had the way to load views both ways.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where have you declared hoursLabel??

Comment: @VishalSonawane The label, just like any other subview, is connected to the file's owner's class via outlet.

Comment: P.s. `nameOfClass` returns a string, when I have the view with `MyView.xib` and `MyView.swift` classes, the method successfully returns `"MyView"`. It returns the same result no matter the view's class was set to the MyView OR the view's File's owner was set to MyView.

Comment: I think you you call fromXib, the self.nameOfClass is not the one where you have declared your outlet. So compiler is not finding the key for your hoursLabel.

Comment: @VishalSonawane ok, I think you are right about the reason of the error, but show me please how to do this right then :)